# Django migrate multiple databases

Tags: python, django, migration

Environment: Django 2, Python 3.6, PostgreSQL (optional)

I am writing an application with multiple models, some of them might be stored in different databases.

Example:

models.py  (might be in different apps)

```
# this used to allow field 'database' to be processed in 'Meta'
models.options.DEFAULT_NAMES = models.options.DEFAULT_NAMES + ('database', )

class MyModel01(models.Model):
    ...
    # this goes to default database


class MyModel02(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        database = 'mydb02'


class MyModel03(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        database = 'mydb03'
```

routers.py:

```
class MyRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return getattr(model._meta, 'database', None)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return getattr(model._meta, 'database', None)

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        model = hints.get('model')
        if not model:
            return None
        if db != 'default':
            modelname = model_name or model._meta.model_name
            usedb = getattr(model._meta, 'database', None)
            if not usedb:
                return False

            if modelname and usedb:
                return usedb == db
            return False
        else:
            usedb = getattr(model._meta, 'database', 'default')
            return usedb == db
        return None
```

settings:

```
DATABASES: {
    'default': {
        # some db settings
    },
    'mydb02': {
        # db settings
    },
    'mydb03': {
        # the SAME db settings as for mydb02
    }
}
```

The issue is that in settings there might be the same database set for all database aliases.

When I run migrate the migration get applied to just one of the databases, but not always to required one. For example it gets applied to 'default', but not 'mydb03'.

I suppose the mistake is in my router, but cannot find out correct implementation.

Comment: It seems the issue is hard to track and to fix. I ended up with having different schemas inside one database (postgresql).

Comment: Do you use any options config?

Like this:"'options': -c search_path=schema, public"

If yes, try remove the public after comma.

Comment: Yes, but this does not solve the issue at all. And you might have not only postgres.

Comment: I have this problem too, with multipls schemas(each schema is a distinct database on django settings), but removing public in options works for me.

Comment: In my case they were the same databases and schemas on one of environments. And this is exactly the problem - where migrations table is stored.

Comment: Migration is store on database pass by parameter`--databases`, i have one solution for a problem mult tenancy.  Where my clients have schemes specifieds and i have 2 schemas shared between him(public and general). I manage it with django.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify which database to use:

```
python3 manage.py migrate # default database
python3 manage.py migrate --database mydb02
python3 manage.py migrate --database mydb03
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases

Comment: Yes, of course, and this is the only way to run migration for other db aliases. But if 'default' goes first - it might receive the migration, not intended for it. *That's* the issue.

Comment: You can config a routerdb to ignore some models in public. It's work for me.